# Склонение сложного названия школы

Tags: склонение

Есть ГБОУ РК «КЕРЧЕНСКИЙ УЧЕБНО-ВОСПИТАТЕЛЬНЫЙ КОМПЛЕКС-ИНТЕРНАТ-ЛИЦЕЙ ИСКУССТВ». Он весь склоняется? «Учащиеся учебно-воспитательного комплекса интерната – лицея искусств»

Comment: я напутала... мне главное - не название с дефисами, а склонение....

Comment: как скажете)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы написала так: *Учащиеся учебно-воспитательного комплекса **интернат–лицея** искусств.* *Учащиеся **интернат-лицея** искусств.*

В этом названии приложение "интернат" стоит **на первом месте**, а в такой позиции оно может не склоняться. (Такой вариант кажется необычным и не очень обоснованным.)

**Обычные названия:** ***школа-интернат, лицей-интернат.*** В этом случае оба слова склоняются: *учащиеся школы-интерната, лицея-интерната*.

Тогда надо учитывать традицию написания этого конкретного учебного комплекса. Склонение обоих слов также возможно: *Учащиеся учебно-воспитательного комплекса **интерната–лицея искусств**.*

Такой вариант отчасти поддерживается формой "**комплекса интерната**-лицея", где склоняются рядом стоящие существительные.

Answer (score 2):

Я посмотрела документацию этого учреждения, там название состоит из трех существительных с дефисным написанием "комплекс-интернат-лицей", тогда они все должны склоняться (запись через **два дефиса**).

Получается: *Учащиеся учебно-воспитательного **комплекса-интерната-лицея** искусств.*

**Аккредитация**

Приказ №2573 от 16.10.17   "О государственной аккредитации образовательной деятельности Государственного бюджетного общеобразовательного учреждения Республики Крым «Керченский учебно-воспитательный **комплекс-интернат-лицей** искусств»"

http://licey-iskusstv.ru/index/dokumenty/0-112

Answer (score 0):

Если есть родовое слово, то название в кавычках не склоняется: работа выполнена в федеральном государственном бюджетном учреждении "Национальный медицинский исследовательский центр онкологии им. Н.Н. Петрова". (Ответ с «Грамоты.ру»).

Answer (score 0):

Правильным будет написание: "Учащиеся учебно-воспитательного комплекса-интерната-лицея искусств", равно как "ученики Онлайн Гимназии №1" можно склонять без дефиса. Всегда смотрите официальное название учреждения, от него и отталкивайтесь при склонении.